# Is changing the hostname on a remote Ubuntu 16.04 safe?

Tags: postfix, hostname

When installing a Postfix mail server I learned that the hostname is an important part of the servers FQDN.

But the servers hostname is not related to the domain name I'm hosting or the SSL cert for my domain... and I need to use secure SMTP.

Should I change the hostname? or can I achieve secure SMTP using masquerading?

I'm concerned if I change the hostname on my remove server I'll run head first into a brick.

this command looks to take care of all the details 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/hostnamectl.1.html

or I could manually edit these..
/etc/hosts
/etc/hostname

but can/should I make it work via masquerading instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have console access through a KVM of some sort? If so, that should help you if you do get into a bind. That said, simply changing the server's hostname shouldn't be a problem, unless you have a [STIG'd](https://iase.disa.mil/stigs/Pages/index.aspx) server with FIPS compliance (I'm betting that's unlikely).

You'll want to run the `hostname` command, AND you'll want to edit `/etc/hostname`, as if you don't edit the `/etc/hostname` file, next time the server reboots, it will revert back to the original hostname.